# How to directly use a prop with ngClass in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to style my component directly based off props, but am unsure how to do it directly with ngClass. Simple representative example below:

HTML (Parent)

```
<myComponent size="large" color="red">
</myComponent>
```

HTML (Child)

```
<div [ngClass]="'standard-class' + size + color">
//content
</div>
```

Typescript (Child, inputs only)

```
@Input() size: string
@Input() color: string
```

Thanks

Comment: `[ngClass]="'standard-class' + size + color"` should be good, have you tried it? What's the result?

Comment: The construct is correct. Are you possibly missing hyphen b/n the words? `<div [ngClass]="'standard-class-' + size + '-' + color">`. Are you sure the CSS selector with the class name generated using `[ngClass]` is defined?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this, my original code was correct except for one detail. I did not include spaces, so the `class` would come through as `"standard-classlargered"`, rather than `"standard-class large red"`.

Note, as the below comment says, I could also use an array:

```
[ngClass]="['standard-class', size, color]"
```

Comment: Instead of adding spaces, you can also pass them as an array. `[ngClass]="['standard-class', size, color]"` See the [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) documentation.

Comment: nice spot, thanks. I'll use that approach instead